Updating Chrome shows this?
I get this: Malformed entry 1 in sources file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources (URI parse)
What am I supposed to do to finish my update?
Thank you

There is a error on line 1 of the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources which will have been added to your system by someone with sudo rights. You need to correct the error. We're limited to details you provide in your question; we don't know what release you're using (thus the format of the file) AND cannot see the contents of that file unless provided details in your question.

"What am I supposed to do to finish my update?" You are supposed to open that file, look at entry 1, locate the problem, fix the problem, and then save the repaired file. Beware of typos and other mistakes -- a human made one error already that caused the problem.

This question is similar to: How do I remove a malformed line from my ubuntu.sources?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Are you using 24.04 or 24.10?

I use version 24.04.1 and the person with sudo rights is me.

I noticed the error message says: E:malformed entry 1 in sources file/etc/apt/sources.list.d/third-party.sources (URI parse) The source could not be read. Could the "E:" be a USB key from which files would have been installed?
